# Insert mutilpe values using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedures and below is my requirement,
I need to come up with stored procedure to populate data for my table(Eg below) for past 4 months with different values for T_KEY,A_KEY,M_KEY and G_KEY.

```
mysql> select * from R_A_METRICS;  
+---------------------+------------+-----------------+-------+------------+  
| TIMESTAMP           |  T_KEY      | A_KEY           | M_KEY | G_KEY         

| 2017-06-30 00:00:00 |    a        | b               | c     | d                         
| 2017-06-30 00:15:00 |   a1        | b1              | c1    | d1
```

Below is my sample procedure to populate 4 months data,

```
PROCEDURE `POPULATE_A_METRICS`()  
BEGIN  
DECLARE START_DAY TIMESTAMP;  
DECLARE END_DAY TIMESTAMP;  
SET START_DAY = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH;  
SET END_DAY = CURDATE();  
WHILE (START_DAY <= END_DAY) DO  
insert into R_A_METRICS values(START_DAY,T_KEY,A_KEY,M_KEY,G_KEY);  
SET START_DAY = START_DAY + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE;  
END WHILE;  
END
```

I want to set the value like @T_KEY=a,a1,a2 and insert it in round-robin way to the table.
Similar requirement for other columns like A_KEY,M_KEY,G_KEY

Any ideas on how this can be achieved through stored procedure ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

To crate a sequence of inserted values like a,a1,a2, you must have a temporary value and store the current sequence to be stored:

```
delimiter $$
DROP PROCEDURE  IF EXISTS `POPULATE_A_METRICS`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `POPULATE_A_METRICS`()  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE START_DAY TIMESTAMP;  
    DECLARE END_DAY TIMESTAMP;  

    SET START_DAY = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH;  
    SET END_DAY = CURDATE();  

    set @counter = '';  /*a counter, blank at first*/
    set @T_KEY = 'a';
    set @A_KEY = 'b';
    set @M_KEY = 'c';
    set @G_KEY = 'd';

    WHILE (START_DAY <= END_DAY) DO  

        insert into R_A_METRICS (`TIMESTAMP`,T_KEY,A_KEY,M_KEY,G_KEY)
        values (START_DAY,@T_KEY,@A_KEY,@M_KEY,@G_KEY); 

        SET START_DAY = START_DAY + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE;  

        set @counter = @counter + 1 ; /*increase counter and concatenate bellow: */
        set @T_KEY = concat('a',@counter);
        set @A_KEY = concat('b',@counter);
        set @M_KEY = concat('c',@counter);
        set @G_KEY = concat('d',@counter);

    END WHILE;  
END$$
```

After execution you will get:

```
mysql> SELECT `TIMESTAMP`,T_KEY,A_KEY,M_KEY,G_KEY FROM R_A_METRICS;
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| TIMESTAMP           | T_KEY | A_KEY | M_KEY | G_KEY |
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2017-11-02 20:00:00 | a     | b     | c     | d     |
| 2017-11-02 20:15:00 | a1    | b1    | c1    | d1    |
| 2017-11-02 20:30:00 | a2    | b2    | c2    | d2    |
| 2017-11-02 20:45:00 | a3    | b3    | c3    | d3    |
| 2017-11-02 21:00:00 | a4    | b4    | c4    | d4    |
| 2017-11-02 21:15:00 | a5    | b5    | c5    | d5    |
| 2017-11-02 21:30:00 | a6    | b6    | c6    | d6    |
| 2017-11-02 21:45:00 | a7    | b7    | c7    | d7    |
| 2017-11-02 22:00:00 | a8    | b8    | c8    | d8    |
| 2017-11-02 22:15:00 | a9    | b9    | c9    | d9    |
```